# How can I set the style of the EditText.setError() icon to the ones used in the default style while using a different theme?

Tags: android, styles, themes

When you setError on an edittext in an activity which has no theme set, it shows a nice dialog with the error text in it.

How can I set it to that style when using a different theme for the activity like Holo.Light ?

Comment: If your theme inherits from any of the system themes, it should provide you with some default image. Use `setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon)` to provide your own icon. You can always copy the drawables used by the system into your resource folders and point to it that way. (You can find the platform resources in <android-sdk-directory>/platforms/android-##/data/res/ directory on your machine)

Comment: This changes the error icon within the edittext but not the message drawable below it. That is what I actually wanted to change.